# Having trouble with kern_return_t error

Tags: ios

I am getting the following error when I try to compile with the code below it. I don't know how to fix it. I have googled. Also asked others, but nobody has been able to help me.
Compiling on mac through theos.
I would really appreciate it if someone can help me.

Error output

```
error: assigning to
  'kern_return_t' (aka 'int') from incompatible type 'uint *'
  (aka 'unsigned int *')
err = reinterpret_cast<uint *>(address* sizeof(data));
```

Code

```
bool writeData(vm_address_t address,  string str) {

//declaring variables

kern_return_t err = 0;
mach_port_t port = mach_task_self();

size_t find = str.find("0x");

if (find != -1) {

    str.replace(find, 2, "");
}

int len = str.size();

 char data[len / 2];

int x = 0;

for(int i = 0; i < len; i += 2) {

    string dat = str.substr(i, 2);
    uint8_t tmp;
    sscanf(dat.c_str(), "%hhx", &tmp);
    data[x] = tmp;
    x++;

}

//set memory protections to allow us writing code there

err = vm_protect(port, (vm_address_t)address, sizeof(data), NO, VM_PROT_READ | VM_PROT_WRITE | VM_PROT_COPY);

//check if the protection fails

if (err != KERN_SUCCESS)
    return FALSE;

//write code to memory

err = reinterpret_cast<uint64_t *>(address* sizeof(data));

if (err != KERN_SUCCESS)
    return FALSE;

//set the protections back to normal so the app can access this address as usual

err = vm_protect(port, (vm_address_t)address, sizeof(data), NO, VM_PROT_READ | VM_PROT_EXECUTE);

if (err != KERN_SUCCESS)
    return FALSE;

return TRUE;

}
```